# How to transform a flat grid into a nested grid?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid-layout

I would like to transform a flat grid described as an array of items having coordinates and sizes into a nested grid packed with children organized into rows and columns.

EDIT: In the first version of this question, I used the term of "matrix" to talk about the grid in its flat state. That was probably confusing, the real purpose of this question was to go from flat to tree. Anyway, one could easily transform a matrix into a flat array such as the one I use to then convert it into a tree.

Having a flat grid such as :

```
var grid = [
    {x:0,y:1,w:1,h:3,id:'f'},
    {x:0,y:0,w:9,h:1,id:'e'},
    {x:1,y:1,w:4,h:2,id:'a'},
    {x:5,y:1,w:2,h:1,id:'b'},
    {x:5,y:2,w:2,h:1,id:'c'},
    {x:5,y:3,w:2,h:1,id:'h'},
    {x:1,y:3,w:4,h:1,id:'g'},
    {x:7,y:1,w:2,h:1,id:'i'},
    {x:7,y:2,w:2,h:1,id:'j'},
    {x:7,y:3,w:2,h:1,id:'k'},
];
```

The result would be :

```
var grid = [
  {
    "w": 9,
    "h": 4,
    "children": [
      {
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 9,
        "h": 1,
        "id": "e"
      },
      {
        "w": 9,
        "h": 3,
        "children": [
          {
            "w": 8,
            "h": 3,
            "children": [
              {
                "w": 8,
                "h": 1,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "x": 7,
                    "y": 3,
                    "w": 2,
                    "h": 1,
                    "id": "k"
                  },
                  {
                    "x": 1,
                    "y": 3,
                    "w": 4,
                    "h": 1,
                    "id": "g"
                  },
                  {
                    "x": 5,
                    "y": 3,
                    "w": 2,
                    "h": 1,
                    "id": "h"
                  }
                ],
                "x": 1,
                "y": 3
              },
              {
                "w": 8,
                "h": 2,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "w": 4,
                    "h": 2,
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "w": 4,
                        "h": 1,
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "x": 7,
                            "y": 2,
                            "w": 2,
                            "h": 1,
                            "id": "j"
                          },
                          {
                            "x": 5,
                            "y": 2,
                            "w": 2,
                            "h": 1,
                            "id": "c"
                          }
                        ],
                        "x": 5,
                        "y": 2
                      },
                      {
                        "w": 4,
                        "h": 1,
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "x": 7,
                            "y": 1,
                            "w": 2,
                            "h": 1,
                            "id": "i"
                          },
                          {
                            "x": 5,
                            "y": 1,
                            "w": 2,
                            "h": 1,
                            "id": "b"
                          }
                        ],
                        "x": 5,
                        "y": 1
                      }
                    ],
                    "x": 5,
                    "y": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "x": 1,
                    "y": 1,
                    "w": 4,
                    "h": 2,
                    "id": "a"
                  }
                ],
                "x": 1,
                "y": 1
              }
            ],
            "x": 1,
            "y": 1
          },
          {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 1,
            "w": 1,
            "h": 3,
            "id": "f"
          }
        ],
        "x": 0,
        "y": 1
      }
    ],
    "x": 0,
    "y": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: The sample matrix doesn't seem to match the output. How are columns and rows organised?

Comment: Oh you're right ! I edited the result array. The logic here is that the matrix should be converted into rows of columns. Each column containing several rows should be split into rows, and so on...

Comment: Clear as mud. ;-) If you provide a sample matrix and sample out put *from the sample matrix* you might get an answer.

Comment: Haha ;) Sorry, I'm tired and kind of muddy myself right now. And I'm not sure how I could describe the process well enough. That should be the correct output now given the sample matrix.

Comment: We may not even need the "height" property in the output after all.

Comment: Your output json is invalid. There are two braces with two arrays within, yet lackig property names. Also The global structur is two arrays after each other - contained wherein?

Comment: Grrr, it seems I'm _very_ tired. Sorry about that. It is good - for real - now ;)

Comment: Is the matrix provided as an array of strings, e.g. `['aaabbbbbcccc', 'aaagggggcccc', 'dddddddddddd']`, or just a single string with new lines or other delimiter like `'aaabbbbbcccc\naaagggggcccc\ndddddddddddd'`?

Comment: In fact it is a string that is then converted to an array of string. But it could be either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go and try to figure this out myself.

I admit the question was badly formulated, so I edited it to make it more accurate.

To reduce a flat grid to a nested grid, the needed steps are :

- Loop over all children.
- Check neighbours in all directions to see if they are adjacent.
- Group the item and its neighbours into a new item.
- Recompute the group size.
- Continue until there is only one child.

I made a github repo with my module : https://github.com/jide/GridPack